# Python adding user input to dictionary/list

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

I am VERY new to python and have found myself very confused. Can anyone help me out or maybe better explain how I could get the output that I am wanting? I have a current dictionary that includes my "inventory" and list that includes my "dragonLoot". I am trying to create a function that asks the user if they would like to add anything else to their inventory and then add those to my standing dictionary list. I know I have the first function right, but I'm having trouble understanding what to change in the second function. This is what I have so far:

Thank you for any help you can provide,again I am extremely new to this and still struggling with functions

```
def displayInventory(myInv):
    print("Inventory:")
    total = 0

    for k,v in myInv.items() :
        print(str(v) + " " + k)
        total = total + v
    print("Total number of items:" + str(total)) 

def addToInventory(inventory,addedItems) :
    addedItems = input("What would you like to add to your your Dragon Loot? Enter D when finished ")
    if addedItems not in dragonLoot :
        inventory.update({addedItems})
    if input == "D" :
        return dragonLoot

addToInventory(inventory,addedItems)

inventory = {'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 42, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 12}#Create your inventory dictonary
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']

displayInventory(inventory)
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: It's not really clear what you want. If I enter "gold coin" does that mean I want to add one gold coin? Two? At some point you need to add one or some other number to the inventory. Your code doesn't deal with the math at all.

Comment: you are not splitting the input, so you have a big string entered by the user in `addedItems`, other thing is  `if input == "D" :`, you are comparing "D" with a function (`input`) not a string.

Comment: I am confused on the math portion. I understand that I would add 1 of the item inputted if it is listed in my dictionary already. Otherwise, I will create a new item within that dictionary. But getting to that point has me so confused. Again, I am very new to this. Thank you!!

Comment: @EmilyMcWilliams Check my answer. I am making some changes, allow me some time.

Comment: Thank you!! Once I get into loops/functions I get lost quickly. The split() function makes much more sense, I was thinking I would have to do those separately at first.

Comment: @EmilyMcWilliams Check now and if it helps please accept the answer. If you have any questions, comment below my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, When you are trying to add a new item to the dictionary, you have to use `split()` function. It will allow the user to input two values on the same line. I have done some basic changes, do the rest of your own.

```
def displayInventory(myInv):
    print("Inventory:")
    total = 0

    for k,v in myInv.items() :
        print(str(v) + " " + k)
        total += int(v)
    print("Total number of items:" + str(total)) 

def addToInventory(inventory,dragonLoot) :

    new_Item = int(input("How many Items you want to add? "))
    counter = 0
    while (new_Item != counter):
        
        name_Item, quantity_Item = input("What would you like to add to your your Dragon Loot? Enter D when finished :").split()
        if name_Item not in dragonLoot :
            inventory[name_Item] = quantity_Item
        counter +=1




inventory = {'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 42, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 12}#Create your inventory dictonary
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
addToInventory(inventory,dragonLoot)
displayInventory(inventory)
```